# How can I add sticky navigation bar to my webpage

Tags: css

I'm working on my first web page and ran into an issue with finding the right code for my sticky nav bar. The nav bar already has a jQuery code attached to it so I'm wondering if that may affect the code, or if I'm not using the right one.Here's the HTML for the nav bar...

```
                <div id="tab_container">
                    <nav id="tabs">
                        <ul id="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Our Staff</a></li>
                            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">book</a></li>
                            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
                            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
```

Heres my css for it...

```
 #tab_container
{
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 970px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#tabs 
{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 970px;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav 
{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 970px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
}

ul
{
    float: left;
    max-width: 970px;
    display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
}

ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 158px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li a
{
    color: #54544b;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    line-height: 70px;

}

a:hover
{ 
    color: #CF7BA1;
}

.active a
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #CF7BA1;
    background-color: #222;
}
```

And for the jQuery I've already included....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul#nav li').click(function(){
    var number = $(this).index();
    $('.sec').hide().eq(number).show();
            $(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
    $('ul#nav li').not(this).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');

});

    $('.sec').not(':first').hide();

});
```

Comment: what would be the best jquery to use?

Comment: I may have not been specific. I want the nav bar to stick to the top of the page when the page is scrolled past its fixed position. In other works I need a scrollable nav bar that remains at the top of the page.

Comment: Simply use position:fixed . See this http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/42Rqf/

Comment: This is merely a `CSS` question. It has nothing to do with jQuery, jQuery plugins, CSS3 or HTML5.

Comment: Are you looking something like this http://www.jay-han.com/tutorial/smart-sticky-nav/

Comment: yes,my nave bar is below my logo so when I change the position to fixed it stays fixed at the bottom of the page. I wish to make it fixed to the top only when the page is scrolled past the point to where it would not be visable anymore.

Comment: Look at their **[tutorial](http://www.jay-han.com/2011/11/10/simple-smart-sticky-navigation-bar-with-jquery/)**

Comment: Ah yes....well then you definitely need Jquery for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `position:fixed;`

```
 #tab_container
 {
background-color: #1E1E1E;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
display: block;
position: fixed;  //change this to fixed....to stick to top
max-width: 970px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
 }
```

You have to compensate for the height of the header though, in your container div, so notice in my demo I have padding of 200px added to "bodydiv" to compensate

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMs8C/3/)

Comment: Jquery has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 1):

To make it sticky you would use `position: fixed` in the css. That makes it stay in the same position relative to the browser window. You don't have to use any jQuery for this part.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have a nav bar that is sticky even without using javascript, jquery or any other scripting languages. You only need to add another attribute to your CSS code. 
Everything that does the magic is the `position: fixed` attribute. The `position` attribute denotes the type of the position of a particular division in HTML. It is followed by the attribute(s) that mention the pixel position. They are `top`, `bottom`, `right`, and `left`.
Here is the code:

```css
#tab_container
{
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 970px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}

#tabs 
{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 970px;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav 
{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 970px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
}

ul
{
    float: left;
    max-width: 970px;
    display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
}

ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 158px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li a
{
    color: #54544b;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    line-height: 70px;

}

a:hover
{ 
    color: #CF7BA1;
}

.active a
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #CF7BA1;
    background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<div id="tab_container">
                    <nav id="tabs">
                        <ul id="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Our Staff</a></li>
                            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">book</a></li>
                            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
                            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <p> Some Text <p>
                <p> Some Text <p>
                <p> Some Text <p>
                <p> Some Text <p>
                <p> Some Text <p>
                <p> Some Text <p>
                <p> Some Text <p>
                <p> Some Text <p>
                <p> Some Text <p>
                <p> Some Text <p>
                <p> Some Text <p>
                <p> Some Text <p>
                <p> Some Text <p>
```

Here we are using `position: fixed` followed by `top: 0px` because we want the nav bar to always be fixed at 0 pixels from the top of the screen. 
If you are looking for a STICKY one, as the question says, you better opt for `position: sticky`. Hope it helps.

If You want to know more about the `position` attribute in CSS, please visit https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp